# Trying to store randomly generated lists in a list, then adding to them later

Tags: c#

Here is a simplified version of my code. Essentially what is going on:
I have an rng, that randomly selects objects from external list, and generates a random assortment of objects into a new list, the length of which is selected by the user.

i.e. User selects 4, 4 objects are selected at random from a list, put into a new list.

I need to store THAT LIST OF 4 in a new list, and iterate through that loop each time until there are no more objects in the original list.

i.e. 4 obj are selected, stored in studentGroupList[0], next 4, stored in studentGroupList[1], etc until external list is empty.

The problem I'm having is that I have no idea how to store lists in lists correctly, and I have no idea how to iterate through those nested lists to display objects, and add to or modify them later, in an organized manner.

Concise explanation of execution: User selects length of lists to be stored, (4 for the example)
4 objects are selected and removed from initial list;
those 4 objects are store in currentGroupList
currentGroupList needs to be store in index [0] of studentGroupList
clear currentGroupList to store 4 more random objects.
loop until initial list is empty.

be able to add to and modify lists in studentGroupList as needed/iterate through all indexes in list of lists.

Please help!

```
        /
    public static void GroupListMaker(List<string> students, int numberOfStudents)
    {
        //User selects size of groups
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a groups size: ");
        int groupSize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //Creates rng
        Random rng = new Random();
        //First String for storing strings
        List<List<string>> studentGroupList = new List<List<string>>();
        //temporarily stores names in list for later storage in studentGroupList
        List<string> currentGroupList = new List<string>();

        int selector = numberOfStudents - 1;
        int groupNumber = 1;

        //while there are students left to sort
        while (students.Count > 0)
        {
            //Assign random student to variable
            string thisStudent = students[rng.Next(selector)];
            //Add variable to current list
            currentGroupList.Add(thisStudent);
            //Remove selected student from list
            students.Remove(thisStudent);
            //Reduce randomization selector
            selector--;

            //If the size of the group and list size are equal, or there are no students left to sort
            if (groupSize == currentGroupList.Count || students.Count == 0)
            {                 
                groupNumber++;

                studentGroupList.Add(currentGroupList);
                currentGroupList = new List<string>();
                //demonstrates data is being stored properly
                Console.WriteLine(studentGroupList[0][0]);
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: do you know what iterators are? This is an easy task for the `yield return` mechanism

Comment: not yet, no, but I'm not averse to learning about them! I'll give them a google search.

The thing I'm really struggling with is simply adding things to the existing lists nested within the main list. if the lists are uneven and I have some left over, i need to be able to add those to the preexisting lists, and I have no idea how to do that.

I feel like if I knew how to demonstrate that the data is in fact being stored, then I could figure out how to add more data easily, but I'm struggling

Comment: we don't see all of your code but the only real issue I see here is: `currentGroupList.Clear()` - this will remove everything from your list and so you end up with nothing - what you want there instead is just `currentGroupList = new List<string>()` (don't forget to add the very-last to  `studentGroupList` too)

Comment: Rest of code added, I felt that the original section was the most important. What you suggest about currentGroupList = new List<string>() i can demonstrate that the lists are storing data now, but how do I iterate through them, when I try nested for loops I get an out of range exception.

Comment: why not just `foreach (var group in studentGroupList) { foreach (var student in group) { ... }}`?

Comment: When I attempt to access data from studentGroupList[1][anything] I get an out of range exception. It isn't storing multiple lists to the list.

Comment: That isn't working. When I execute I get the same name printed 3 times. 

I'm not exactly sure the syntax of the foreach, I've read about it elsewhere, but I can't find any bare bones explanations for what's going on in the for each. There's no iterating or looping happening, just the same value printed 3 times.

Comment: sorry but you will have to debug this for yourself then (should be rather easy) - on first glance the code should work (with my proposed changes)

Comment: May I ask what the `numberOfStudents` parameter is for? It looks to me like it's just `students.Count` and not really needed as a method parameter at all. Or is it some other value? See my answer below for a working example of iteration and without seemingly unnecessary variables :)

Comment: part of the assignment is that the method accepts arguments student list and number of students. If there are 13 students, and students.count is 13, then rng.Next(students.Count) should produce an index up to 13, which could produce an out of range exception, I would think anyway. So I created another variable called selector which reduced 13 to 12, so that there would only be 13 indexes.... at least that's what I thought

Comment: @nathanrogers `rng.Next(13)` produces values from 0 to 12, so everything is alright with `rng.Next(students.Count)`. That's why the `selector` stuff above always misses the last element (until the end). `Next` is well-designed for working with indices :) So no need for selector!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me, and I see no need for the `selector` variable if I guess its purpose correctly. If it really serves as a count of `students`, there was also a logical error, as `rng.Next(selector)` would only take values up to `selector-1`, but since `selector`is the count minus 1, it is a valid index itself! I also removed the `groupNumber` variable, since it coincides with `studentGroupList.Count`.

You can just plug this code into an empty project's `Main` method and debug it to see what's happening.

If you still have problems with `IndexOutOfRangeException`, please post the code you used to try and iterate through `studentGroupList` and where *exactly* the exception occurs. Other than that, there is not much we can do, and it's up to your debugging skills :)

```
  List<string> students = new List<string> { "Peter", "Lisa", "A", "B", "C", "F", "J", "K" };

  Random rng = new Random();

  List<List<string>> studentGroupList = new List<List<string>>();
  List<string> currentGroupList = new List<string>();

  Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
  int groupSize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  while (students.Count > 0)
  {
    string thisStudent = students[rng.Next(students.Count)];
    currentGroupList.Add(thisStudent);
    students.Remove(thisStudent);

    if (groupSize == currentGroupList.Count || students.Count == 0)
    {
      groupNumber++;          studentGroupList.Add(currentGroupList);
      currentGroupList = new List<string>();
    }
  }

  // this iterates over all lists in studentGroupList,
  // then over all students in the current list and prints them;
  // it separates the printed groups by empty lines
  foreach (List<string> group in studentGroupList)
  {
    foreach (string student in group)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(student);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }

  Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I wonder what was so different in mine. This works, with all of the arguments the way I had it set up. I don't see a whole lot of difference between the 2, but yours iterates well, and only stores 1 isntance of each variable, rather than multiple copies like mine was.

Comment: This brings me to another question, if there is an odd amount (say 13) and you want to distrubute remainders among preexisting lists, how could you do that?
Say there are 13 entries, and the user selects 5 per group, that makes 2 groups of 5 with 3 left over. How can I distribute those three evenly between the existing two groups?

Comment: This is what I would change, but I don't know how the list of lists is working at this point, so I don't know what syntax to use. .Insert? not .add for sure, but idk how   if (groupSize == currentGroupList.Count || students.Count == 0)
                {
                    if (groupSize > currentGroupList.Count)
                    {
                        //Any leftovers can be sorted into different groups
                    }
                    
                    studentGroupList.Add(currentGroupList);
                    currentGroupList = new List<string>();
                }

Comment: @nathanrogers Sorry, but I guess (I'm kind of a newb here myself) that this would merit a new question on this site, as it is only vaguely related to the original problem :) Sadly, by just looking at yours I don't know either why there is is such a big difference between your original implementation and mine.

Comment: @nathanrogers Also, I don't understand why you would do it. The user enters the group size, but then you end up with groups bigger than that. If you really want to, I'd check `student.Count < groupSize` as condition for "not enough students left for a full group", and then there'd have to be some more logic to determine how exactly to distribute stuff. For example, what about 12 students, group size 8? Would you then want to end up with just one group of 12? Determine what you want and then you can post it as a new question along with the problem of how to access the groups themselves :)

Comment: @nathanrogers For completeness: You should use `.Add()` once you have the group, e.g. `for (int i=0; i<studentGroupList.Count; i++) { studentGroupList[i].Add(someStudent); ..... }`. But as I said above, that may not be enough, for instance in the case where there are more students left than there are existing groups. Do you want to go over them again? Anyway, already too much in the comments ;)

Comment: I tried it that way. Essentially, if you have a class of 5 students and you want even groups, 1 person will be by themselves, I want the left out students to be included with the left over groups. 

The goal of the program is to make even as possible groups. with noone left out

I can put an error check to see if userInput > (students.Count / 2) so that there are not uneven groups that way